# Rebus - System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Rebus.Bus.IBus.Send'

Tags: c#, .net-core, rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

When calling `SendRequest` using `Rebus.Async`, I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Rebus.Bus.IBus.Send(System.Object, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2)'.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your NuGet package versions. Make sure one isn't a prerelease version while the others are stable.

For me, I had installed a Rebus extension that depended on the prerelease version of another Rebus package. Updating all Rebus packages to the latest (prerelease where applicable; latest stable otherwise) versions fixed the issue.